# Is it right to double 'both'

Tags: sentence-construction

Take the following sentence:

> Radians aren't Imperial and degrees aren’t Metric, they’re both both.

They are trying to say that both radians and degrees are both imperial and metric. Is it correct to say it in this way? It sounds a little bit weird.

I'm not asking if it's the best way to say the sentence, only if it's correct to say it like this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct.  It's barely intelligible, but technically correct.  It illustrates nicely there is such a thing as being too concise.